# Differentiating a function (a differential operator) with respect to a variable the function does not directly depend on??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, homogeneous-equation

I am studying about second order homogeneous equations with constant coefficients of the form:
**L(y) = y'' + a1y' + a2y = 0**
A possible solution to this would be **e^rx**, where r is a constant. By subbing this in, we find that this would be the solution if the characteristic polynomial **p(r)** (which is a quadratic in terms of r) equals zero.
In the case that the roots are equal, then **p(r)=p'(r)=0**.
In order to use this extra information that **p'(r)=0** (to get another distinct solution), we differentiate our homogeneous equation **w.r.t r**, currently in the form: **L(e^rx)=p(r)e^rx** .. Here I have a problem with the differentiation on the left hand side. According to my text, the differentiation goes:
(as shown in image)

So apparently, we just ignore the function L, and directly differentiate **e^rx** with respect to r, **inside** the function L. The text says we do this, because L involves differentiation only with respect to x. I'm not getting how they differentiated here, I'm not able to apply any of the standard rules of differentiation (which i know of). Can someone explain this differentiation process a little better?

[image: the text i'm referring to]

Comment: I think this is most likely from S.L Ross. Although I'm not sure because our sir just shared  the pdfs of each part, he didn't specify the book.

Comment: I think the author just switched the order of the derivatives

Comment: oh ok, thanks very much for the help.

Comment: You're welcome Karun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\partial_r (L(e^{rx}))=\partial_r (\partial_{xx}(e^{rx})+a_1\partial_x (e^{rx})+a_2e^{rx})$$
$$\partial_r (L(e^{rx}))=\partial_r \partial_{xx}(e^{rx})+a_1\partial_r \partial_x (e^{rx})+a_2\partial_r e^{rx}$$
You switch the order of derivatives:
$$\partial_r (L(e^{rx}))=\partial_{xx}\partial_r(e^{rx})+a_1\partial_x \partial_r(e^{rx})+a_2\partial_re^{rx})$$
$$\partial_r (L(e^{rx})=L(\partial_r(e^{rx}))$$
Finally:
$$\partial_r (L(e^{rx})=L(xe^{rx})$$

Comment: So, ∂xx∂r(erx) = ∂r∂xx(erx) . Is this always true?

Comment: Not always true but you can check Schwartz Theorem @karunmathews ...

Comment: Here on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives